# "[object Object]" issue regarding my filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filter

Below is my code. I'm finished with the functionionality and have the feature nearly working. I'm running a filter on my state which grabs my API. My console log does return what I expect(an object with the properties all listed). The only issue  I'm having is when I go to type in the input, it says [object Object] and returns all the objects. I considered dropping a JSON.Stringify inside my filter function to turn every property into an string. Would this be the proper solution/way to go about thinking?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Villagers({ people }) {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState(people);

  const filter = (e) => {
    const keyword = e.target.value;

    if (keyword !== "") {
      const results = people.filter((user) => {
        console.log(user);
        return user.name["name-USen"]
          .toLowerCase()
          .startsWith(keyword.toLowerCase());
      });
      setUserName(results);
    }
    setUserName(people);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input type="search" value={userName} onChange={filter} />
      </div>
      {people.map((villager, index) => {
        return (
          <ul key={index}>
            <Link to={`/villagers/${villager.id}`}>
              <li>
                <img src={villager.icon_uri} alt="" />
                {villager.name["name-USen"]}
                <br />
                {villager.personality}
              </li>
            </Link>
          </ul>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: somewhere, you're using an `Object` where a `string` is expected ... it's not clear to me  where, but knowing that, you should be able to spot it easier than me

Comment: your `filter` function will result in `setUserName(people);` to be always executed, regardless of the value of `keyword`

Comment: @JaromandaX I originally tried removing the line of setUserName(people), but the input remains as [object Object] whenevere a key is stroked.

Comment: What is [object Object] whenevere a key is stroked? Is it the console statement " console.log(user);" output? Or the value of input?